# "make generate" doesn't generate any files

Tags: c, makefile

I would like to compile MuPdf for Android following [these](http://www.mupdf.com/doc/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android) Steps. I stuck at building the native code libraries. Following error appears:

```
"Compile thumb : mupdfcore <= pdf_cmap_table.c
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:5:35: fatal error:
../generated/cmap_cns.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated. make: ***
[obj/local/armeabi/objs/mupdfcore/__/__/pdf/pdf_cmap_table.o] Error 1
```

I suppose this file has to be generated, because the command "make generate" shows me following line:

```
GEN generated/cmap_cns.h ;  ./build/debug/cmapdump
generated/cmap_cns.h
```

It doesn't throws any errors.

I searched my whole hard drive for this file, i can't find it and there is also no generated folder.

**Further info**:

OS: Win7
Make Command: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm

Comment: Is there a configure?  Maybe they forgot the configure step.

Comment: My spidey sense also wonders if this is related to regular vs. debug libraries.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with configure. I'm new to gnu c and such things. I just want to implement a pdf reader to my android app :D. There were no file named configure, just Makefile, Makerules and Makethird.

Comment: Ok, Makerules is the configuration file.

Comment: How are you building it? Mingw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
make generate NOX11=yes
```

And/Or:

http://nondroid.blogspot.com/2012/06/mupdf-android-library-build.html

Comment: doesn't help :/
i typed "make generated" instead of "make generate" and it shows me: ' ' ' ' MKDIR generated ; mkdir -p generated, but i can't see any generated folder

Comment: Wow, you link helped me. Thank you.

Comment: @user1911196  Any luck?